# R and Big Data Analysis

Tags: r, big-o, bigdata

I am looking for some suggestions on using R for analysing Big Data - i.e., data that runs into TBs.

Typically I think that it is better to preprocess the data and load just the information that the user needs in order to perform analysis. However, if say information from a large dataset (say, 200 GB) needs to be aggregated, I think first, having the data stored in column databases rather than row-oriented DBMS would be more efficient. Second, for CPU intensive data analysis, it is probably worthwhile having some distributed computing capabilities using RHadoop / RHIPE. Also, if there are multiple enterprise users, what would be the best way to implement these ... (say 10 researchers who are concurrently working on large datasets)

I have found some resources on the web such as the R indexing, mmap packages to do efficient computations in R but wanted to get some feedback from those who have actually worked and implemented these at an enterprise level.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions,

Regards.

Comment: This question is not constructive, and is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. That being said, my experience is that R chokes on data sets anywhere near your use case. I'd advise aggregating in the database or distributed system that holds the data and then pulling the aggregations into R.

Comment: Interesting question but...
In its current form, the question doesn't fit the typical format for StackOverflow; it will likely be closed.  Altough, still not a good fit for http://stats.stackexchange.com/,  you may get a slightly better reception there, as there are many R and/or big-data practionner on cross-validated.  I can second `Jack Maney`'s comment:  R isn't a good fit for big data; excellent for modeling, plausibly useful for visualisations or computation based on pre-aggrated input, but despite attempts to mmap it,  it remains a unlikely tool for big data.

Comment: See: [High Performance Computing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html)

Comment: If you want to use R in the enterprise for big data, then one option is [Revolution Analytics](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/) who provide enterprise support for R on big data.

Comment: @Andrie I think it's good practice here to [**disclose affiliations**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion)!